# PowerShell Copying latest folder to another folder

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I am trying to copy the latest folder on a remote sever to a local folder using robocopy without any luck any suggestions

Comment: what latest folder means ? last written date?

Comment: You've neither described how the "latest folder" is determined nor shown what you've attempted thus far. SO expects that you'll put a minimum amount of effort into describing the issue and demonstrate what you've done to attempt to complete the task.

Comment: ROBOCOPY "\\Source" "destination\Migration_Staging" *db_7.0.0.0.zip

Comment: looking for the last file written to a folder or last folder written to a directory

Comment: Still confusing what is last written to a folder or last written to a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Its

```
ROBOCOPY \\sourceserver\share c:\local /MIR
```

(Mir)Mirror a directory with subfolders incl. empty directories

```
robocopy \\server\share c:\localfolder /MIR
```

more here 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx